# Method to check if username exists in database

Tags: php, mysql, wordpress

I have this method which checks if a username exists in the database:

```
public function checkUsername($username) 
{

    global $wpdb;
    $result = $wpdb->get_row( "SELECT * FROM {$wpdb->prefix}users WHERE con_username =".$username);
    if(!empty($result)){

        return false;
    }

}
```

I am then checking the username like so:

```
if(!$users->checkUsername($_POST['email'])){
        $error++;
        $error_msg[]='Email already exists!';
    }
```

However this isnt working as it is telling me that every username i try already exists. I dont think i have the returns written correctly.. Any ideas??

Comment: try with "user_email" intaed of "con_username"

Comment: and when you are doing the `WHERE` clause you need to add quotes in the text strings: `WHERE user_email = 'email'`

Comment: and finally, you are trying to get the user by email or by name? in SQL sentece are searching by name but in php code are setting $_POST['email']. You need to fix this.

Comment: @bri `if(!empty($result)){

        return false;
    }` <br/> use with if statment `else{ return true; }`

Comment: Please show all fields of the `users` table. I guess you look for email in the wrong place -- `user` instead of `email`.

Answer (score 2):

You are not returning anything if the email not found and so `checkUsername` will return `null` in this case.

`$users->checkUsername($_POST['email'])` will always `empty` or `null`.

Try with -

```
return empty($result);
```

The function should be -

```
public function checkUsername($username) 
{

    global $wpdb;
    $result = $wpdb->get_row( "SELECT * FROM {$wpdb->prefix}users WHERE con_username ='".$username."'");
    return empty($result);

}
```

And check -

```
if(!$users->checkUsername($_POST['email'])){
```

And try to implement some security to input data.

Comment: Updated the answer. `'`s were missing around username.

Comment: The issue is not with SQL, that seems to be running fine. Its the return that seems to be wrong. The way i thought it should be written is if result is not empty means that the username is already taken. So return false if not empty..? Does this sound correct?

Comment: When i change the method to just "return empty($result);" it allows for users to be added with the same email...

Comment: `var_dump($result)` and see what you are getting inside the function.